# Маршрутизация по IPtables

Tags: iptables, nat, ubuntu

Есть сеть 192.168.1.0/24. В ней есть група PC, которым необходим доступ всего на один сайт. В сети есть маршрутизатор на Ubuntu Server 11.04 его IP - 192.168.1.4. Необходимо чтобы если клиент "цепляется" по протоколу HTTP на 192.168.1.4:80 получал доступ к сайту, скажем www.yandex.ru. То есть чтобы IPtables подменял в пакетах ip адреса так, чтобы пакеты уходя с маршрутизатора 192.168.1.4. Шли на www.yandex.ru, а обратно через этот же маршрутизатор (на нём подмена адресов источника и назначения) возвращались на PC в локальной сети. То есть PC думают, что цепляются браузером на 192.168.1.4. А 192.168.1.4 исправляет и передает пакеты на www.yandex.ru и обратно... Нужно чтобы это работало на Сетевом уровне модели OSI. Примечание: Сайт www.yandex.ru взят для примера.

Comment: Так а в чем у вас проблема? Больше похоже на учебное задание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для такого случая вам не обходимо

1. Использовать цепочку PREROUTING, где с помощью DNAT заменить IP получателя (в локальной сети) на IP яндекса (в глобальной), не забыв при этом указать фильтр для порта и источника (вашей группы PC), если нужно
2. Использовать цепочку POSTROUTING, где с помощью SNAT заменить IP источника на IP-адрес вашего сервера, но уже внешний, здесь фильтр можно сделать только по порту 80

Таким образом, пройдя два правила пакет полностью превратится из локального в глобальный, на обратном пути все будет наоборот.